# Is it possible to delete records from MySQL based upon the date they were inserted

Tags: mysql

I have a MySQL table. The table does not have a timestamp, yet I would like to delete all records entered after a certain date. I tried using created_at, but had no luck.

```
DELETE FROM table_name where created_at > '2021-02-09 00:00:00';
```

I was under the impression that MySQL maintained an insertion date that I could leverage in my delete statement.

EDIT:

I don't have a create_at column so I made to modify my question. Is it possible to delete the last 100 records inserted. I have this query that accurately selects the last 100 records, but how would I now delete them:

```
SELECT * FROM (SELECT * FROM table ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 100) var1
ORDER BY id ASC;
```

Comment: 'I was under the impression that MySQL maintained an insertion date' - nope that's not the case..please add your table definition as text to the question.

Comment: This `created_at` field misunderstanding is the side-effect of learning MySQL solely with the "help" of ready-made frameworks/cms'.

Comment: As far as I know, MySQL doesn't keep track of row insertion times, neither does it keep any ID that could help to approximate it such as Oracle's `ORA_ROWSCN`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, that's not possible.

You need to include a created date in your table definition (and maintain its values) in order to delete rows depending on their creation.

---

Amendment to address to OP's edit about deleting by id:

If you have an incrementing id you can easily delete n rows in descending order. Just ORDER and LIMIT your DELETE query.

E.g., to delete the 100 rows with highest id:

```
DELETE FROM table ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 100
```

Comment: It IS possible, but the OP needs to set the groundwork first on the table, as you allude to in your answer.

Comment: @Martin given I don't have a created_at column is it possible to delete the last n row inserted.  I have a query above the selects them, when n =100, but am I able to delete them?  Will definitely add the created_at column in the future.

Comment: @Mutuelinvestor see my edit for a simple delete-highest-n-ids query.

Answer (score 2):

> Is it possible to delete records from Mysql based upon the date they were inserted

This is **only** possible if you also record the date the row was inserted at the point of insert.

Luckily, this is quite easily to set out with a new MySQL table, requiring minimum upkeep and maintenance ongoing.

When you `CREATE` the table, you should add a row that is a `timestamp` column that can then be set as the insert date by setting the default value as `CURRENT_TIMESTAMP`. You can then use this column in your `DELETE` query, as others have referenced.

(It is usually useful to also index this column).

## Example

**Table Creation**

```
CREATE TABLE `database`.`tableName` ( 
    `id` INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT , 
    `created_at` TIMESTAMP NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP , /* THIS COLUMN */ 
    `some_column` VARCHAR(50) NULL DEFAULT NULL ,
    `some_other_column` INT NULL DEFAULT NULL , 
    PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE = InnoDB;
```

Note from this the `created_at` column will hold the date and time stamp of the row generation.

Now;
when you insert data, you can ignore this column because the value will be auto generated by MySQL.

```
INSERT INTO `tableName` (`some_column`) VALUES ('horses!')
```

**Output**

> ```
> id    created_at              some_column      some_other_column
>  1    2021-02-12 13:28:53     horses!          NULL
> ```

So from this you can then DELETE as you require.

```
DELETE FROM tableName WHERE `created_at` > '2021-02-09 00:00:00'
```

**Warning**

If you add the `created_at TIMESTAMP NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP` column definition retroactively, then the timestamp will be the date the *column* was generated, **NOT** the date the existing rows were inserted. But future inserts will be correct.